# Hackers are trying to do something on one of our site

Tags: asp.net

One of our site recently received a lots of attack which all seems similar. By chance, we have a error logging framework which send us error log email when something strange happen or an error raised on the server.

Here is what happen :

```
Error : The file '/(A(u76U7llazAEkAAAAZTJmYmE1NmMtZTE4YS00YzQ2LTlmYzItNGIxMzZjMzNjOTc4vkp-I-8cYbLrHx25-IfNdMvuKao1))/MostOfOurPublicPage.aspx' does not exist.
Request:
URL: http://Ourwebsite.com/(A(u76U7llazAEkAAAAZTJmYmE1NmMtZTE4YS00YzQ2LTlmYzItNGIxMzZjMzNjOTc4vkp-I-8cYbLrHx25-IfNdMvuKao1))/MostOfOurPublicPage.aspx
User Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; SiteBot/0.1; +http://www.sitebot.org/robot/)
Referrer: 
Host: 213.186.122.2 (Ukraine)
SecuredConnection: False
```

User-agent shows SiteBot/0.1 but I'm preaty sure its not ... at least I never heard anything about sitebots doing things like that.

**Question**
So, anyone have any idea of what the heck is that and what can I do to prevent this things because it make our error logging framework sending us something like 100 error logs a day!

*Note : I usualy talk french so sorry for my english.*

Comment: And we now not receive anymore errors... so I hope they haven't found what they needed!

Comment: We've also tell that to the website's hoster, and they tell us back it was a "Malwares CnC" and difinitily block the 213.186.122.2 address in case that you also had a similar issue with this IP Address

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a search bot or crawler. Place a robots.txt file on your web server root (http://www.example.com/robots.txt) and put the text below in it.

```
user-agent: sitebot
disallow: /
```

That should keep it away.

Also the strange url it uses, is just a session cookie passed by a url string, instead of a cookie.

Comment: You are right, there was a cookieless attribute in our web.config I've not saw. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: But note that the this IP was see as a "Malwares CnC" according to our web hoster... so they simply banned this IP from the server.

Answer (score 1):

These types of issues seem to crop up from time to time. You probably don't want to fully suppress these types of errors as they can be helpful from time to time to determine bad links. What I have done in the past is filter out bot traffic.

- either block the traffic at your firewall
- filter the bot traffic.